# Export multiple NPM packages from single directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, rollup

Suppose a Node app which is a "micro-UI". So it has its own UI components, maybe some Redux stuff, some classes to make API calls, etc.

I have need to export some part of this repo for consumption in other micro-UIs:

- API classes should be exported as `my-project-api` NPM package.
- UI things (React router, Redux stuff, UI components, API classes, etc.) should be exported as `my-project-ui` NPM package.

In other micro-UIs where I need the API classes from this repo (but not the UI components), I'll install `my-project-api` via NPM.

In the "main UI" project which gathers all micro-UIs and build a single SPA from them, I'll install `my-project-ui` via NPM.

---

So, my `package.json` needs to support publishing multiple package (e.g. the `name` field needs to be flexible). How can this be accomplished without splitting the API source from the non-API source?

I think the answer is likely to split out the API components / UI components into their own packages in the same repo. But I'm wondering if there's another way.

Comment: You should look into [monorepos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monorepo), it might be a good solution for your use case. I can't provide more detailed help as I've never tried it myself but I've heard good things about using [pnpm workspaces](https://pnpm.io/workspaces)

Comment: Yes, we are going for a hybrid approach where each UI lives in the same repo as its API so we can run the API/UI "standalone". But then for deployment we pull the UIs into a "wrapper" UI that brings it all together. This turns 10 SPAs into 1 large SPA with each micro-UI as a "module" within it. Modules can be optionally enabled based on the customer / deployment we're targeting.